# new mysqli connection Throws access denied error for root user

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am new to PHP. I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using mysqli. I created a new user, and it didn't connect and threw the access denied error. I gave database-specific grant in PHPMyAdmin, but still throws error. Then I tried with the root user as well, and it still throws the same error. Here's my code:

```php
<?php

// create mysqli connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname');

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo 'Connected to the database successfully!';
```

I don't understand why that is happening. Please help me! Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: We don't know the credentials for your database, sorry. This isn't really a code problem.

Comment: @ADyson I am using root user and the password by default for root user is blank.

Comment: @Barmar Error is: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /path/to/php/file/with/error/

Comment: That error message indicates that you used an empty username when you called `new mysqli()`.

Comment: @Barmar But u can see in the code I have passed root for the username

Comment: Clearly it's not coming from that code. It doesn't lie.

Comment: `the password by default for root user is blank`...maybe by default, but perhaps you or someone else changed it. The database isn't lying to you, it's clearly telling you that you submitted invalid credentials.

Comment: And yes `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' ` cannot be from the code shown in the question. It's simply impossible. Double-check what you're telling us and showing us is all from the same place. The error message will include a filename and line number.

Comment: @Adyson I got that. There were some permission errors. XAMPP wasn't able to install some dependencies due to some permissions that it required but didn't have. The issue is solved. Thanks!